# If $f$ is holomorphic, what is the meaning/intuition behind $f_z=f'(z)$ and $f_{\overline z}=0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, intuition

If $f$ is holomorphic then we know the derivative of $f$ with respect to $z$ is defined, i.e., $f'(z)$ exists. But $\overline{z}$ is a different variable, so if we take the derivative of $f$ with respect to a different variable, isn't it obvious the derivative will be $0$?

Is there something I'm failing to understand about if $f$ is holomorphic, then $f_z=f'(z)$ and $f_{\overline z}=0$?

Comment: No, $\bar z$ depends on $z$, so it is not obvious that its derivative with respect to $\bar z$ is nonzero. In fact, if we choose $f(z)=\bar z$, it is obvious that $f_{\bar z}$ is nonzero. The fact that $f$ is holomorphic is very relevant.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff If $f(z)=\overline z$, where $z=x+iy$, I found $f_z=0$ and $f_{\overline z}=1$. Does that imply that $f$ is not holomorphic?

Comment: @AlJebr: Yes, because holomorphic is either defined as or equivalent to (depending on what you're reading) $f_{\bar z}=0$.

Answer (score 1):

1. Case $x,y,u(x,y),v(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}$ are all real-valued (as  opposed to complex-valued). (This is the normal case.) The Dolbeault operators are defined as
   $$ \partial ~:=~\frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x}  -i\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \right) \quad\text{and}\quad \bar{\partial} ~:=~\frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x}  +i\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \right).\tag{A}$$
   It is easy to see that the [Cauchy-Riemann (CR) equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations) are satisfied iff $f\equiv u+iv$ satisfies $$\bar{\partial}f~=~0.\tag{B}$$ 
   In the affirmative case, the function $f$ is [complex differentiable/holomorphic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_function), and
   $$ \frac{d f}{dz}~=~\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} ~=~\frac{1}{i} \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}~=~\partial f \tag{C}$$
   holds.
   Note that 
   $$ z~:=~x+iy \quad\text{and}\quad\bar{z}~:=~x-iy \tag{D}$$
   are *not* independent variables.
2. Case $x,y,u(x,y),v(x,y) \in \mathbb{C}$ are all complex-valued (as  opposed to real-valued). (This is the unusual case.) Define *independent* complex variables $z$ and $\bar{z}$ via eq. (D). Note that the bar in $\bar{z}$ no longer denotes complex conjugation. The inverse transformation reads
   $$ x~=~\frac{z+\bar{z}}{2}\quad\text{and}\quad y~=~\frac{z-\bar{z}}{2i}. \tag{E}$$
   The chain rule yields
   $$ \frac{\partial}{\partial z}  ~\stackrel{(E)}{=}~\frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x}  -i\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \right) \quad\text{and}\quad \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}} ~\stackrel{(E)}{=}~\frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x}  +i\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \right),\tag{F}$$
   which resembles eq. (A). For this reasons we often infuse some of the notation from case 2 into case 1 whenever no confusion can arise. See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/89002/2451) related Phys.SE post.

Comment: what does "independant variables" mean ?

Comment: @mercio: Do you know what dependent variables are?

Comment: I guess I don't ? (I know only in a probabilities context when talking about random variables)

Comment: E.g. $2x+3$ and $3x-4$ are not independent variables because if you know the value of one, you can deduce the value of the other.